# What are the different strategies for resolving a recursive type bound?

Tags: rust, type-systems

I have the following code that attempts to create a composite trait that includes all the different value/reference combinations for a method of two arguments.

```rust
#![recursion_limit = "10"]

// Create a trait with some methods
pub trait Methods2<Other> {
    type Output;
    fn min(self, other: Other) -> Self::Output;
}

// Create a composite trait that contain multiple traits
trait AllCombos<NonRef>:
    Methods2<NonRef, Output = NonRef> + for<'a> Methods2<&'a NonRef, Output = NonRef>
{
}

impl<T, NonRef> AllCombos<NonRef> for T where
    T: Methods2<NonRef, Output = NonRef> + for<'a> Methods2<&'a NonRef, Output = NonRef>
{
}

// Implement this trait for f32
impl Methods2<f32> for f32 {
    type Output = f32;
    fn min(self, other: f32) -> Self::Output {
        self.min(other)
    }
}

impl Methods2<f32> for &f32 {
    type Output = f32;
    fn min(self, other: f32) -> Self::Output {
        (*self).min(other)
    }
}

impl Methods2<&f32> for f32 {
    type Output = f32;
    fn min(self, other: &f32) -> Self::Output {
        self.min(*other)
    }
}

impl Methods2<&f32> for &f32 {
    type Output = f32;
    fn min(self, other: &f32) -> Self::Output {
        (*self).min(*other)
    }
}

// Create a struct with a generic float inside
#[derive(Debug)]
struct MyStruct<Float> {
    x: Float,
}

// Implement to Methods2 trait for MyStruct
impl<Float> Methods2<MyStruct<Float>> for MyStruct<Float>
where
    Float: AllCombos<Float>,
    for<'a> &'a Float: AllCombos<Float>,
{
    type Output = MyStruct<Float>;
    fn min(self, other: MyStruct<Float>) -> Self::Output {
        MyStruct::<Float> {
            x: self.x.min(other.x),
        }
    }
}

impl<Float> Methods2<MyStruct<Float>> for &MyStruct<Float>
where
    Float: AllCombos<Float>,
    for<'a> &'a Float: AllCombos<Float>,
{
    type Output = MyStruct<Float>;
    fn min(self, other: MyStruct<Float>) -> Self::Output {
        MyStruct::<Float> {
            x: (&self.x).min(other.x),
        }
    }
}

impl<Float> Methods2<&MyStruct<Float>> for MyStruct<Float>
where
    Float: AllCombos<Float>,
    for<'a> &'a Float: AllCombos<Float>,
{
    type Output = MyStruct<Float>;
    fn min(self, other: &MyStruct<Float>) -> Self::Output {
        MyStruct::<Float> {
            x: self.x.min(&other.x),
        }
    }
}

impl<Float> Methods2<&MyStruct<Float>> for &MyStruct<Float>
where
    Float: AllCombos<Float>,
    for<'a> &'a Float: AllCombos<Float>,
{
    type Output = MyStruct<Float>;
    fn min(self, other: &MyStruct<Float>) -> Self::Output {
        MyStruct::<Float> {
            x: (&self.x).min(&other.x),
        }
    }
}

// Lifts a variable into MyStruct
fn lift<Float>(x: Float) -> MyStruct<Float>
where
    Float: AllCombos<Float>,
    for<'a> &'a Float: AllCombos<Float>,
{
    MyStruct { x }
}

// Create an element
fn main() {
    let bar = lift(4.0_f32).min(lift(2.0_f32));
    //let bar = lift::<f32>(4.0_f32).min(lift::<f32>(2.0_f32));
    println!("{:?}", bar.x);
}
```

This generates the compiler error

```
error[E0275]: overflow evaluating the requirement `&'a MyStruct<_>: Methods2<MyStruct<_>>`
   --> src/main.rs:119:15
    |
119 |     let bar = lift(4.0_f32).min(lift(2.0_f32));
    |               ^^^^
    |
    = help: consider adding a `#![recursion_limit="20"]` attribute to your crate
    = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `for<'a> AllCombos<MyStruct<_>>` for `&'a MyStruct<_>`
    = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `Methods2<MyStruct<MyStruct<_>>>` for `&'a MyStruct<MyStruct<_>>`
    = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `for<'a> AllCombos<MyStruct<MyStruct<_>>>` for `&'a MyStruct<MyStruct<_>>`
    = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `Methods2<MyStruct<MyStruct<MyStruct<_>>>>` for `&'a MyStruct<MyStruct<MyStruct<_>>>`
    = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `for<'a> AllCombos<MyStruct<MyStruct<MyStruct<_>>>>` for `&'a MyStruct<MyStruct<MyStruct<_>>>`
    = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `Methods2<MyStruct<MyStruct<MyStruct<MyStruct<_>>>>>` for `&'a MyStruct<MyStruct<MyStruct<MyStruct<_>>>>`
    = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `for<'a> AllCombos<MyStruct<MyStruct<MyStruct<MyStruct<_>>>>>` for `&'a MyStruct<MyStruct<MyStruct<MyStruct<_>>>>`
    = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `Methods2<MyStruct<MyStruct<MyStruct<MyStruct<MyStruct<_>>>>>>` for `&'a MyStruct<MyStruct<MyStruct<MyStruct<MyStruct<_>>>>>`
    = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `for<'a> AllCombos<MyStruct<MyStruct<MyStruct<MyStruct<MyStruct<_>>>>>>` for `&'a MyStruct<MyStruct<MyStruct<MyStruct<MyStruct<_>>>>>`
note: required by `lift`
   --> src/main.rs:109:1
    |
109 | / fn lift<Float>(x: Float) -> MyStruct<Float>
110 | | where
111 | |     Float: AllCombos<Float>,
112 | |     for<'a> &'a Float: AllCombos<Float>,
113 | | {
114 | |     MyStruct { x }
115 | | }
    | |_^
```

Now, this can be resolve by replacing the call to `lift` with the full qualified syntax, which was commented out in the above code

```rust
let bar = lift::<f32>(4.0_f32).min(lift::<f32>(2.0_f32));
```

Though that works, it a larger code, it results in annotations everywhere, which is burdensome.  I'd like the original call

```rust
let bar = lift(4.0_f32).min(lift(2.0_f32));
```

to work.  I can sort of make this happen by replacing the implementation of the `AllCombos` trait

```rust
impl<T, NonRef> AllCombos<NonRef> for T where
    T: Methods2<NonRef, Output = NonRef>
        + for<'a> Methods2<&'a NonRef, Output = NonRef>
{
}
```

with explicit implementations for each type

```rust
impl AllCombos<f32> for f32 {}
impl AllCombos<f32> for &f32 {}
impl AllCombos<MyStruct<f32>> for MyStruct<f32> {}
impl AllCombos<MyStruct<f32>> for &MyStruct<f32> {}
```

Then, everything works as expected.  However, this is somewhat inconvenient because it must be specified for all new types, twice.  Are there different options that preserves the generic implementation of `AllCombos`, but doesn't subsequently require fully qualified syntax for all function calls to methods within that trait?

Comment: This looks like a bug. The type `f32` should be inferable but, somehow, the bound `for<'a> &'a Float: AllCombos<Float>`  is causing the type-checker algorithm to go down a recursive path before it tries the more straightforward route of inferring from the argument type.

Comment: This is an older question, but I've answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66631251/why-do-i-get-an-overflow-evaluating-the-requirement-error-for-a-simple-trait-i). Summary: this is a compiler issue that has yet to be resolved and there's no good workaround.